# Moment toJSON does not consider timezione

Tags: momentjs, angular-moment, moment-timezone

I've angular application with moment@2.24.0.
I do this simple actions:

```
 let test = moment('2019112200:00','YYYYMMDDmm:ss');
 console.log(test .toJSON());
```

the result is

```
2019-11-21T23:00:00.000Z
```

i think it doesn't consider timezone. With

```
moment.locale('it')
```

the result is the same.

The workaround can be moment.format() but i would use the right solution.

Here fiddle to replicate https://jsfiddle.net/crakdelpol/r6yu2abL/1/

Comment: From [`toJSON()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-json/) doc: _When serializing an object to JSON, if there is a `Moment` object, it will be represented as an ISO8601 string, adjusted to UTC._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A valid alternative is

```
test.ISOString(true)
```

Result is: `2019-11-22T00:00:00.000+01:00`